# Looping through ColdFusion Query and Incrimenting a Counter

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a scenario where I record a 'date of last completed' for a task as a column in my database as well as an interval period (in days) for the next scheduled task in another column. I would like to add that date to the maintenance period and if it is greater than #now()#, tick a counter so that I can tally up that toal for all records.

Here is how I attempted that but I am confused on the logic. My value is always zero so I'm clearly doing something wrong.The number should be 17 as I manually calculated it by going through my database records by hand.

```
<!--- Get list of all active equipment--->  
<cfquery name="get_equipment_tally" datasource="#datasource#">
select *
from equipment_maintenance
where active = 'yes'
ORDER by customer_name
</cfquery>

<cfset counter = 0>

<cfloop query="get_equipment_tally">
<!--- Set the due date for service = the particular maintenance interval  added to the last service date. --->

<cfset dueDateTally = dateAdd("d", maintenance_interval , Date_last_completed) /> 

<!--- Get list of all active equipment that needs maintenance today---> 
<cfquery name="get_equipment_attention_tally" datasource="#datasource#">
select *
from equipment_maintenance
where active = 'yes' AND #dueDateTally# <= #now()#
ORDER by customer_name
</cfquery>

<cfset counterNew = #counter# + #get_equipment_attention_tally.recordcount#>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#counterNew#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: counterNew will always be 0 (counter) plus the result of your last query's recordcount in the loop.  So if the last query recordcount is 0, then counterNew will always be 0.

Comment: So how should I change then?

Comment: If I am understanding what you are trying to do, I would change counterNew to counter in both the cfset and the cfoutput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wish to tally the number of maintenance dates before now() and the number after now(), then the code logic can be much simpler. Something like:

```
<!--- Get list of all active equipment--->  
<cfquery name="get_equipment_tally" datasource="#datasource#">
select *
from equipment_maintenance
where active = 'yes'
ORDER by customer_name
</cfquery>

<cfset counter_after_today = 0>
<cfset counter_today_or_before = 0>

<cfloop query="get_equipment_tally">
<!--- Set the due date for service = the particular maintenance interval  added to the last service date. --->

<cfset dueDateTally = dateAdd("d", maintenance_interval , Date_last_completed) /> 

<cfif dueDateTally LTE now()>
    <cfset counter_today_or_before = counter_today_or_before + 1>
<cfelse>
    <cfset counter_after_today = counter_after_today + 1>
</cfif>

</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
    counter_today_or_before: #counter_today_or_before# <br>
    counter_after_today: #counter_after_today#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: So this makes a lot more sense and is definitely an easier way. Thank you.

Comment: A loop is not necessary just to calculate a total, and querying within a loop does not scale well.  Is the code actually using the rest of the query data for something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with one query.  Something like this:

```
<cfquery name="theQuery">
select field1, field2
, case when your date logic is one thing then 1 else 0 end dateLogic

from etc
<cfquery>

<cfset yourNumber = arraySum(theQuery['dateLogic'])>
```

You can work out the actual details.

**Edit**

Your actual case logic might be something like this:

```
, case when dateadd(day, maintenanceInterval, date_last_completed) <= getDate() then 1
else 0 end isOverDue
```

Note that I don't use MySQL so I am using MSSql syntax.

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie with coldfusion so I'm having trouble following your example. Can you explain the case part of your example further?

Answer (score 0):

You may be over-complicating things. If the goal is simply to count how many equipment items are scheduled for maintenance any time today, or in the future, you do not need a loop at all. It can be done with a single query. Simply apply the appropriate date filter and `COUNT(*)` the records:

```
<cfquery name="get_equipment_tally" ...>
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalItems
   FROM   equipment_maintenance
   WHERE  DATE_ADD(Date_last_completed, INTERVAL maintenance_interval DAY) 
            >= <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>Total Items: #get_equipment_tally.totalItems# </cfoutput>
```

**NB:** Adjust the cfsqltype if needed. Type `cf_sql_date` includes the current date *only*.Type `cf_sql_timestamp` includes the current date AND time.